# What engine & setup can I use to analyze a Bughouse position from a single board only (one board), taking into account the pieces in hand?

Tags: engines, analysis, bughouse

I have looked at the Sjeng and the [Bughousechess.wz.cz](http://bughousechess.wz.cz/BughouseEngines/) website and the answers in the other page. This is not quite a Crazyhouse equivalent analysis, due to the capture mechanics. The pages are very old (Althon, Pentium) and there is no clear statement how to do this.

If necessary, I can take both boards into account, but in particular wanted to see if there was a tactic available.

I have the PGN/screenshot of the position, how can I use Sjeng or similar to analyze it properly?